# How can I keep python from loading the 'wrong' package?

Tags: python, package

There is, apparently, a package loaded in our `Python/2.7.2` environment named `CrossMap` which has, as a subpackage, `tabix`. When I start this version of python and `import tabix`, `tabix` shows: `/hpcf/apps/python/install/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/CrossMap-0.1.6-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/tabix/__init__.pyc` Indicating that it is being loaded from `CrossMap`. Now, even if I `pip install pytabix` (which creates a `tabix.so` file in the `site-packages` directory), it still hits the `CrossMap` version. I even tried installing `pytabix` localling with `pip install --user pytabix`, but it still loads the `CrossMap` version.

How can I point `import tabix` to the `tabix.so` file instead of the subpackage of `CrossMap`?

UPDATE: Even after moving `CrossMap` to 'old_versions' directory, when I try to load `tabix`, it still hits a different package which has `tabix` as a subpackage. When I `import tabix` and then run `tabix`, I get a pysam package from `RSeQC-2.6.1` even though I have `pytabix` as it's own package in the main `site-packages` directory. This same thing happens with the `pysam` package. Any ideas here?

Comment: How much control do you have over the user environment and how much control do they expect? As in, for argument's sake, is it an option for you to give everyone their own virtualenv (not that virtualenv is necessarily your solution, but along those kind of lines of control)?

Comment: It's an option, but it is not pragmatic. I have control over everyone's initial environment via cluster wide .bashrc and, more to the point, the `module` which is loaded when they request to use `python/2.7.2`, so if I wanted to load specialized environment variables, that is where I would do it. The problem with unique virtualenvs is that 25 people might need `package A` and 32 might need `package B`, etc. There would be a lot of redundancy installing those packages in everyone's virtualenv.

Comment: Hmmm.. okay.. before I go nuts and experiment a little - have you had a play around with sys.meta_path / PEP 0302? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302 - (noting this might be overkill, i've just got some spare time tonight and I got curious)

Comment: I have not ... Even just looking over the documentation I have little to now idea what it does! In case it matters, I have the freedom to create system wide python packages which can/should be loaded as 'wrappers' to other modules if it would help. So if a user is having trouble loading `packageX`, we could edit the package, rename it, or write a wrapper for it if need be.

Comment: If you can do that, could you not also wrap the python exec to shove your path to wrappers first in the sys.path (similar to the answer below) and drop your tabix wrapper there?

Comment: (1) How would I do that?! That might be answer to what I'm asking about! (2) If that is the case, would that just force everyone to use `packageX` instead of `packageY/packageX?` as it is now? If so, what about people who want to use `packageY` and are now forced to use `packageX` instead of `packageY/packageX`?

Comment: Also, I should mention that the below answer worked for `tabix`, but not `pysam`, so it is not the goto answer for all issues I am facing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81875/discussion-between-tanantish-and-laurbert515).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're going to need to put pytabix in a directory that occurs earlier in sys.path, or move CrossMap to a directory further down the path.

I like the notion of preferring pytabix. If you could:

1. Modify the system configuration file for your shell (/etc/bash.bashrc) to include something like the following: `export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/stuff/onpythonpath`
2. Use `pip install --target="$HOME/stuff/onpythonpath" pytabix`

Modifying the system-wide config file should put the new path pretty early in `sys.path`.

Another way to prefer pytabix is to install it in editable mode. In my system that has the effect of placing the newly installed package first in sys.path:

Ex:
My path before (which includes "onpythonpath" added by exporting PYTHONPATH in the config file):

```
 ['',
  '/usr/local/bin',
  '/home/keith/devel/onpythonpath',
  '/usr/lib/python2.7',
  '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
  '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

Now after running:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/slowkow/pytabix.git@40e7a78ba6fdfbf72a25da718f530e7c1bad389e#pytabix
```

This is my path:

```
['',
 '/usr/local/bin',
 '/home/keith/src/pytabix',
 '/home/keith/devel/onpythonpath',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to use a `.pth` file in the python version's `site-packages` folder to manually sort the `sys.path` for a user. `easy_install` uses this to add an eggs contents to your path as well.

Comment: Whoa. So many time wasted on this one. I actually had Python package keep loading from the wrong path, even after I've `pip uninstall`ed it. Using your solution found it in one of the files in `ls -la $(python -m site --user-site)/*.pth` and deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install `pytabix` to different folder `pip install --target="/path/to/your_new_path" pytabix` and add this new path to `sys.path`:

`import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/your_new_path")`

and then import like `import your_new_path.tabix`

Comment: I can try that, but I am doing a cluster wide install for multiple users and they are expecting `import tabix` to work out of the box. I'd rather find a solution on the backend to make `import tabix` point to the correct installation. Even if there is a way to modify the environment to do that on their behalf, that would be better. Is that possible?

Comment: to be able to import package with the same name User should install `pytabix` to `C:\Python27` or move `pytabix` folder after installation from `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`to `C:\Python27`. As Python directory is located higher in directory tree and it has been already added to `sys.path`, correct `pythabix` package will be found by simply `import tabix`. This seem to be the most straightforward solution

Answer (score 1):

When any module is imported it looks in to the current directory first ,
after that it starts looking in to the system path, that to in a the order of their appearance(chronological order), 
check using :

```
import sys 
print sys.path
```

So, beginners approach would be swapping the list elements and by putting the path from where we need to import first,  at the 0th index,(swap the list) 
The above could be done , for understanding the concept. (never a good approach in real implementation)

or if you can append a path prior to import

```
import sys
# the PackageFolder dir contains foo.py, bar.py 
sys.path.append('/foo/bar/PackageFolder')

from foo import ChocolateClass
from bar import RunClass,WalkClass
```

A better approach says specify the path from where you want to import the module :

```
import bar
foo = bar.load_source('module.name', '/path/to/file.py')
foo.MyClass()
```

There are equivalent convenience functions for compiled Python files and DLLs.
For Python 3.3+ this is a bit more involved, unfortunately:

```
import importlib.bar
loader = importlib.bar.SourceFileLoader("module.name", "/path/to/file.py")
foo = loader.load_module()
foo.MyClass()
```

Hope this helps .

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a virtualenv for your project. Virtualenv is an excellent way to avoid namespace pollution and contentions like you are having.

To debug a situation where you do not know where a specific module is hiding, you can try to import the specific module in an interactive Python shell and print the `__file__` property for the module. Doesn't work in all cases though, e.g. zipped modules, but can get you started.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the cleanest way to solve this problem is full isolation as provided by a virtual machine hypervisor such as Vagrant, as opposed to partial isolation provided by `virtualenv`.

I don't know if you're familiar with `virtualenv`, but the problem with it is that it only provides python-level isolation. For python packages that depend on system libraries, only the python-level part of those packages are isolated. Both `tabix` and `pysam` seem to have system level dependencies. As such, the creation of a clean virtual environment without `CrossMap` installed should solve the problem.

Whether this is actually a feasible solution for you is a whole other story. I just thought I'd put forward my two cents as the other proposed solutions don't seem to be working for you. I also just personally feel that this is a better and cleaner solution to your problem than messing with sys.path or manually setting modules to point to certain files.

Vagrant is very easy to set up though and is a really easy way for a whole team to be work in the same environment, using their own tools from their host machine that they are accustomed to. See http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/index.html for more details.